# Dark Hairless Spot On Skin

Tags: dogs, skin-condition

While brushing our 5 year old Schnauzer-Poodle we found a bald spot. We have not noticed him trying to lick or rub this spot. It is completely flat, and looks like this:

[image]

**Any ideas on what this could be?**

Comment: has there been any recent vet check-up?

Comment: He is having one right now. I will update once we hear from the Vet

Comment: It's possible it's just dirt, or differnt color skin. Did you try to wash it off? What did you find out at the Vet's office?

Comment: Vet couldn't look at him today. It isn't dirt, hair isn't growing on this spot...

Comment: Where is the spot located? It's very usual for hair to be rubbed off the spots that touch the ground when the dog lays down. My dog has similar spots right in the midle of his chest and on his ellbows.

Comment: It's on top of his right shoulder... indeed but a part that does not rub on the ground. Thanks!

Comment: Were you ever given a diagnosis for this? It certainly looks unlike anything I've seen, wondering if the vet tested for a skin infection.

Comment: @Serpentines25 it went away, never found out what it was...